# How to create a custom view that is initialize only once and common for all activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a custom view in android. With following condition :

1. The view should be initialize only once
2. The same view should be used throughout application

I have tried to initialize the view from application class and adding to the current activity.

Following is the code :

**ViewInAppApplcation**

```
public class ViewInAppApplcation extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new AppActivityCallBack());
}

private class AppActivityCallBack implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    StatusBarView statusBarView = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
        final Activity activity1 = activity;
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (statusBarView == null) {
                    statusBarView = new StatusBarView(activity1);

                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.status_bar_view_holder);
        if (view != null) {
            view.addView(statusBarView, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.status_bar_view_holder);
        if (view != null) {
            view.removeView(statusBarView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

    }
}
}
```

**StatusBarView**

```
public class StatusBarView extends RelativeLayout{

/**Activity context object.*/
private Context context = null;
/** View object */
private StatusBarView statusBarView = null;
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param context - Context Reference
 *
 */
public StatusBarView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.statusBarView = this;
    initView();
}
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param context - Context Reference
 * @param attrs - Set of attributes
 */
public StatusBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    this.statusBarView = this;
    initView();
}

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param context - Context Reference
 * @param attrs - Attribute List
 * @param defStyleAttr - Default Style Attributes
 */
public StatusBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.context = context;
    this.statusBarView = this;
    initView();
}

/**
 * Inflate the app status bar xml and add to view
 */
private void initView() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_app_status_bar, this, false);
    new Asy().execute();
    statusBarView.addView(view);
}


public void setValue(String value) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
    textView.setText(value);

}



private class Asy extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            publishProgress(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "DONE";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        setValue(values[0]+"");

    }
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.next).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
 }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/status_bar_view_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

This code will add a statusbar view to current activity. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Singleton pattern comes to mind

Comment: @Shaishav : The above code is doing the same as you said.

Comment: In each public constructor your are updating the instance which shouldn't really change anything. Shouldn't the private instance be static?

Comment: use dependency injection library like dagger which may work for you [square-Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/), [google - Dagger2](http://google.github.io/dagger/), And why do you want to initialize a view in singleton, I have not seen a code with uses singleton for initializing a view before

Comment: @Shaishav : Reg "registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new AppActivityCallBack());" line ?

Comment: @avinash no, I was talking about the constructor of `StatusBarView`

Comment: @SaravInfern : Will try those library.

Comment: @Shaishav : StatusBarView will be null for the first time, but next time onward it will be not null. We can put a log and check.